# Multilateral PDF annex with one main header in the Appendix

Tags: pdfpages, appendix

I am not really familiar with LaTeX, so please forgive me if I am not quite accurate with my source code and the description:

**Fault Description:**

I need to add a multilateral PDF file (5 pages) to my appendix and need to name this complete document in my appendix as one subsection. Nevertheless at the moment every singe page of the PDF file gets a own continuous subsection.

**Source code:**

```
\section*{Appendix}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\markboth{Appendix}{Appendiy}

\includepdf[landscape=true,page=-,scale=0.8,pagecommand={\subsection{\ac{HA} 
Company Presentation}\label{Company}}]{anlage/CompanyPresentation}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just don't call `\subsection` each page

Comment: The option `pagecommand` is called each time a page is inserted. Try `addtotoc` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a complete pdf file to the appendix and name it something.

If you ask me, I would create a new table of content or add the name of the document to the existing table of content, use a `fancyhdr` (optional) and add the pdf file. This can be achieved easily by the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\renewcaptionname{USenglish}{\contentsname}{Appendix}
\begin{document}
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    {
        \renewcommand\clearpage{}
        \tableofcontents
    }

\includepdfset{pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}

\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={
    1,addsec,1,Description of pdf file,p1}]{\detokenize{pdf-file.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

Table of content would look like this:

[image]

The top of the pdf file in the document would look like this (with the fancy header - without the black bar: I used the black bar to hide personal information):

[image]

Be aware that this method also adds page numbers in the pdf. `fancyhdr` has the big advantage that it is extensively customizable. This could also mean, you have to put some work on it, to make it look exactly the way you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick feedback.
I already tried to implement both proposals however, I received the following error message for owmal proposal:

```
Package scrlayer Error: cannot define '\chead'}
Package scrlayer Error: cannot define '\cfoot'}
```

I am using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,natbib=true, 
            maxbibnames=9, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false, 
            uniquename=false, firstinits=true,dashed=false, 
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: This looks like an elaboration on the original question. If this is your question you'll probably want to log in and add this information to the question (and maybe post a comment).

Comment: Perhaps good to know: you can format code using the “Code Sample” button at the top (labelled “{}”) or by pressing ctrl-K (or cmd-K in MacOS).

Comment: If you are the same person who asked the question it looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Please keep in mind that TeX.SX is a Q&A site, which means that unlike in a normal, linear forum, there is a strict separation between questions, answers and comments. The space here is reserved for answers to the question on top only. If you want to clarify the question, edit it. If you require additional explanations from an answer, add a comment. (Of course you can't do either thing if you got locked out of your original account, see above.) In any case, this post does not constitute an answer and will probably be removed to avoid confusion.